# Wordpress ACF field not working in WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Why does this return all posts;

```
$partner = get_query_var('partner');

echo "Partner ID: ". $partner; // Echoes correctly

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_query' => array(
    'meta_key'      => 'partner',
    'meta_value'    =>  array($partner), // also $partner (without array)
    'compare' => 'LIKE', // Also 'IN'
      ),
    );

$partner_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

the ACF field 'partner' is an array, the query variable is a string (obv)

Comment: I've also done it without the `meta_query` and that returns no posts

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage of `meta_query` is like this:

The args shouldn't be `meta_key` if you're using meta_query - they should be `key`, `value`, etc.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'partner',
            'value'   => array( $partner ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: This produces no results (and I know they are there because I can test for them later from the full set). From reading https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/ I can see they are listing both eg 'meta_key' and 'key'

Comment: OK, I got there (with your wonderful help and that of Mr Taco)
    `$args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                        'key'      => 'partner',
                        'value'    =>  $partner,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        ),
                    ),
                );`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_query' => array(
    'meta_key'      => 'partner',
    'meta_value'    =>  array($partner), // also $partner (without array)
    'compare' => '=', // Also 'IN'
      ),
    );

$partner_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Why is this a good answer?

Comment: Compare is wrong.

Comment: The search operator. Possible values are ‘=’, ‘!=’, ‘>’, ‘>=’, ‘<‘, ‘<=’. Default value is ‘=’.

Comment: This returns all posts

Comment: Try the Howard's solution

Comment: @IronCanTaco; https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/ gives all the values for `compare`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who gets stuck in this rabbit hole.

My query parameter is a string, ACF stores the IDs as a string if there's one and an array if there's more than one.

This form of the arguments returns the correct results. (many thanks to Howard E and IronCanTaco)

```
$partner = get_query_var('partner'); // string

$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'key'      => 'partner', // Could be string or array
                    'value'    =>  $partner,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
            );
```